# Integer-constrained GA default genetic operator functions [Matlab]

Tags: matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I am using `ga()` to run an optimization problem where I have 8 variables, 6 of which have integer constrains.

Everything's ok, but I noticed that Matlab overwrites the Selection, Mutation and Crossover functions (and that is reported [here](http://it.mathworks.com/help/gads/mixed-integer-optimization.html#bs1cifg), in the official documentation).

Although I was not able to find which are the default options in such cases. It's ok for me if Matlab overwrites custom functions for integer problems, but at least I'd like to know what its default behaviour is.

Does anybody know the default Selection, Mutation, Crossover functions in integer (or mixed-integer) problems?

Comment: According to [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/genetic-algorithm-options.html) the default Mutation is [Gaussian](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/genetic-algorithm-options.html#f6633), the default crossover is [scattered](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/genetic-algorithm-options.html#f7820), and the default selection is [stochasit uniform](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/genetic-algorithm-options.html#f6593). Further details are provided at the links. I have eno reason to believe that they'd be different in the mixed integer case. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: And from the link you provided, it seems that it's only the custom functions that aren't permitted. You may well be able to use multiple built-in options for each.

Comment: @horchler, that's why I thought. Although the triplet Gaussian, scattered, stochastic uniform are default value for unconstrained problems (and that's 100% true) whereas in my case I do have some values that are integer constrained. From the link I provided *To obtain integer variables, ga uses special creation, crossover, and mutation functions.* and *ga uses only the binary tournament selection function*.

Comment: So to be fair the selection function is known. Everytime I run an integer-constrained problem, no matter what options I do select for mutation/crossover/creation, Matlab will overwrite it as soon as the `IntCon` vector is non-empty. Such vector is an input parameter for `ga()`